# Creo una lista a partir de otra pero los cambios en una me afectan a las dos...¿Qué hago mal?

Tags: python, pygame

Soy entusiasta de pithon y autodidacta y me encuentro con el siguiente problema:
En un método creo una lista a partir de otra donde he de realizar unos cambios dentro de un bucle, a cada ciclo quiero que la segunda lista creada se vuelva a copiar desde la primera en el estado en el que estaba, pero los cambios que realizo en esta también afectan a la primera. Concretamente se trata de un minimapa donde represento la posición de un personaje en movimiento, pero en lugar de un punto con la posición actual me dibuja un trazo... No sé que hago mal.
La parte del código donde está el problema es el siguiente (utilizo python 3.4 y pygame 1.9.2):

```
# Crea una matriz con el mapa.
def matrizar_minimapa(self):
       # lista que creo a partir de self.matriz_mapa que quiero 
       # que se quede intacta
    matriz = [] 
    matriz.extend(self.matriz_mapa)  
    for element in self.elements.values():
        f,c = self.buscarPos(element.map_pos)

        # Esto me modifica las dos listas ¡¿?!
        matriz[f][c] = 2   

# crea una superficie minimapa donde se representa el mapa y elementos
def get_minimapa(self):
    celwidth = 3
    minimap_w = len(self.matriz_mapa)*celwidth
    minimap_h = len(self.matriz_mapa[0])*celwidth
    matriz = self.matrizar_minimapa()

    pisable     = pygame.image.load('utilidades/imagenes/minimapa/pisable.png')
    nopisable   = pygame.image.load('utilidades/imagenes/minimapa/nopisable.png')
    elemento    = pygame.image.load('utilidades/imagenes/minimapa/elemento.png')
    foco        = pygame.image.load('utilidades/imagenes/minimapa/foco.png')

    minimap_surface = pygame.Surface((minimap_w, minimap_h))
    x = 0
    y = 0
    for f in matriz:
        for c in f:
            if c == 0:
                minimap_surface.blit(pisable, (x,y))
            elif c == 1:
                minimap_surface.blit(nopisable, (x,y))
            elif c == 2:
                minimap_surface.blit(elemento, (x,y))
            x += celwidth
        y += celwidth
        x = 0

    minimap_surface.convert_alpha()
    return minimap_surface
```

Por si sirve de algo, la variable que quiero dejar intacta (que representa el mapa) la creo de la siguiente forma:

```
    # Crea una matriz con el mapa donde 0 es pisable y 1 no.
def matrizar_mapa(self, mapa_nopisable, mapasize):
    matriz = []
    width = 22
    fil = 0

    for y in range(0, mapasize[0], width):
        matriz.append([])
        for x in range (0, mapasize[1], width):
            cel = pygame.Rect(x, y, width, width)
            if cel.collidelist(mapa_nopisable) == -1:
                matriz[fil].append(0)
            else:
                matriz[fil].append(1)
        fil += 1

    self.matriz_mapa = matriz
```

Answer (score 2):

La lista que pretendes duplicar es una *"lista de listas"*. Aunque creas una nueva lista, cada elemento de la nueva lista se crea a partir de las listas originales.

Por aclararlo mejor, supongamos el siguiente código:

```
lst1 = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5]]
lst2 = []
lst2.extend(lst1)
lst2.append(6)

print(lst1)  # -> [[0,1,2],[3,4,5]]
print(lst2)  # -> [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],6]
```

Al añadir la lista `lst1` a `lst2`, se añaden los mismos elementos que tenía `lst1`, no se duplican.

Hay que duplicar también las listas que componen la primera lista. La forma sencilla (y habitual) es usando el operador *slice* `[:]` sin argumentos, aplicado a cada una de las listas:

```
lst2 = [l[:] for l in lst1]
```

Para tu caso, sabemos que únicamente tienes un nivel de listas anidadas y que funciona tal como he puesto. Pero en un caso más general podíamos usar la función `deepcopy` para estar más seguros:

```
from copy import deepcopy

lst2 = deepcopy(lst1)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Me ha servido de gran ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Tuve el mismo problema que tienes. Para resolverlo, por lo menos en mi caso; tuve que usar una variable auxiliar que copiara los elementos de mi primera lista, y que luego sea esa variable la que fuera agregada a mi segunda lista.

`list_aux = firts_list.copy() second_list.append(list_aux)`

Agrega `list() a firts_list.copy()` si quieres que se copie como una lista dentro de la otra