# ¿Cómo puedo evitar la continuidad de un valor dentro de una lista en Python?

Tags: python, lista

Tengo un código en **Python** en cual añado a una **lista (1)** vacía múltiples valores, pero luego deseo que todos esos valores se añadan como una lista a otra **lista (2)** que tengo el el código. Mi problema es que luego de hacer esto, al querer vaciar mi **lista (1)**; el valor almacenado en mi **lista (2)** también se vacía. Es como si existiera una continuidad en  mi **lista (2)** de siempre mantener el valor actual de mi **lista (1)** sin importar que ya no haga ninguna interacción entre ellas.

```
    # Añade una combinación a la lista de combinaciones:
    for x in enumerate(iterators):
        if matrix[x[0]][x[1]] != None:
            combination.append(matrix[x[0]][x[1]])
        else:
            break
    else:
        print("- Lista de iteradores:", str(iterators)[1:-1])
        print("- Combinacion obtenida:", str(combination)[1:-1], end="\n\n")
        combinations.append(combination)
    combination.clear()
```

A mi lista **combination** le agrego una serie de números (Ejemplo: [0, 5, -4, 1, 2]), y luego quiero agregar dicha lista de números para a mi lista **combinations** para quede de la siguiente manera: [[0, 5, -4, 1, 2], [2, -1, 0, 0, 6], [1, 3, -4, 12, 1]]. Pero como dije, al usar el método .clear() para vaciar una lista; al aplicar dicho método en mi lista **combination.clear()**, también me vacía lo que está en mi lista **combinations**.

Comment: Todos enfrentan ese problema alguna vez. En Python los arreglos (listas, tuplas, diccionarios) no se asignan por valor, si no que esa *estructura* (objeto) se referencia a los nombres de variables apuntados a ese objeto. Lo que hagas en una variable afectará a la otra, a menos que especifiques que quieres hacer una copia del objeto que contiene la misma. Ver [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/51669/80870) o [esta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/501815/80870).

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Creo una lista a partir de otra pero los cambios en una me afectan a las dos...¿Qué hago mal?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/51600/creo-una-lista-a-partir-de-otra-pero-los-cambios-en-una-me-afectan-a-las-dos)

Comment: Ya logré resolver el problema. Tuve que usar una variable auxiliar para copiar mis elementos de una lista a dicha variable, y luego esta ser la que sea agregada a mi lista principal. Lo mismo pero con más pasos

`list_aux = list(combination.copy())
combinations.append(list_aux)`